# React function not displayed in "this" but yet still callable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused as to how React functions bind to this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  randomFunction(){
    console.log("Hello World")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this)}
        {console.log(this.randomFunction)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You should see on the console both of these return something, however `randomFunction` is not present in the previous `this` object. As show in the image below

[image]

I am curious to know how/where this link is made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your function is moved to the prototype. This way it is created only once, not per every component instance.

You can verify this by calling `console.log(this.__proto__)` or expanding `__proto__` object visible on your screenshot.